# Radio buttons (with uppercase 'type' in the HTML) in Watir Firefox Webdriver

Tags: firefox, watir, webdriver, firefox4

I use Firefox 4 with Watir Webdriver.
I have a web page with the following:

```
<input id="RadioM" type="RADIO" value="M" name="Field_SEX">Male
<input id="RadioF" type="RADIO" value="F" name="Field_SEX">Female
```

These really seem standard radio buttons to me.
My Watir code:

```
browser.radio( :id , "RadioM" ).set
```

The error message is:

```
C:/Program Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:241:in `ass
ert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:id=>"RadioM", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"radio"} (Watir::Exception::Unknown
ObjectException)
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/radio.rb:
9:in `set'
        from I:/watir/one.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in watir-webdriver - it won't find the input element if the 'type' attribute is upper cased (which is indeed valid HTML).

As a workaround, you can do this:

```
browser.element(:id, "RadioM").to_subtype.set
```

Container#element returns a generic element (in this case avoiding the input type check which is failing for the upper cased attribute), which you can "cast" to a more specific element with Element#to_subtype (which returns a Watir::Radio).

Comment: Can you tell me where I report it?

Comment: You can report it here: https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/issues but Jari is the developer of watir-webdriver, so I guess he is already aware of the problem. :)